# Disable or override GSuite "Verify its you" function

Tags: gmail, mailbox, verification

Theres a weird issue I can't find any solution for: in an organization that is using GSuite admin can't open a mailbox for a fired employee. I mean we can reset password etc but while logging in there's "Verify its you" prompt that will send sms to his private number - that means mailbox  can't be opened.
We are legally entitled by organization management to open the mailbox, but it seems quite impossible.

It is not a 2SV - we have disabled it for the whole domain in attempts.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 4):

As an administrator, [reset their password](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33319), and [use one of their backup verification codes](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9176734).

On top of organization 2SV policy, Google accounts have [extra security](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6002699) when faced with suspicious logins. Such as an admin attempting to login with a new device in a different location. Makes sense an unknown device would trigger a "Verify it's you". G Suite administrators can disable this for a short time. (See Mario R.'s [answer over at webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129484/corporate-gmail-g-suite-login-requires-phone-verification-using-non-existent-p/131906#131906), via [this blog](https://tinyapps.org/blog/201909260700_g_suite_phone_number.html).)

> 1. Sign in to your [Google Admin console](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129484/corporate-gmail-g-suite-login-requires-phone-verification-using-non-existent-p/131906#131906).
> 2. From the Admin console Home page, go to Users.
> 3. Click the row for the user account to
>    display the user information page.
> 4. Click Security.
> 5. Click Login challenge.
> 6. Click Turn Off For 10 Minutes.

Or, skip account takeover. As an administrator, download the user's data via [G Suite Data Export](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458).

Comment: 2SV is disabled. Should I enable it?

Comment: If 2SV is really off, you are instead seeing extra security from suspicious logins. See edit.